# Magento add id attribute to top links

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add id attribute to all top links. I got one solution as below

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><liParams>id="myaccount"</liParams></action>
```

Adding liParams works for My Account link only this solution not works for My Cart and Checkout links.

Comment: Which magento version???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Link uses below function located at `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php`

```
public function addCartLink()
    {
        ////.....
        $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
        return $this;
    }
```

You can see that it does not contains any `<liParams>` or `<aParams>`. While the `addLink()` method located at `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` contains the params as shown below

```
public function addLink($label, $url='', $title='', $prepare=false, $urlParams=array(),
        $position=null, $liParams=null, $aParams=null, $beforeText='', $afterText='')
```

Thus you can do either of the following

1. Override the **addCartLink()** in your local and add params as
   needed
2. Remove the checkout link and then again add it with explicit URL and
   params

For example in your `local.xml`, to add a custom link to Top Links via local.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: THanks! I will look into it! If it works, you'll get a nice checkmark!

Answer (score 3):

@Nilesh Yadav,cart and checkout link are use different methods for create top link

```
<action method="addCartLink"></action>
   <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
```

Other used `addLink` function

Checkout  and Cart use class  `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links` function `addCheckoutLink and addCartLink`

Modify xml code

```
  <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"><liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink">  <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

and `Copy app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php`
to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php
```

goto function modify logic in addCartLink

```
 public function addCartLink($liparams=null)
 {
.....
if(is_null())
{ $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
}else
{
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, $liparams, 'class="top-link-cart"');
}
```

....

Also

```
  public function addCheckoutLink($liparams=null)
    {
....
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $text = $this->__('Checkout');
        if(is_null()){
            $parentBlock->addLink(
                $text, 'checkout', $text,
                true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
                'class="top-link-checkout"'
            );
    }else{
            $parentBlock->addLink(
                $text, 'checkout', $text,
                true, array('_secure' => true), 60, $liparams=null,
                'class="top-link-checkout"'
            );

        }
        }
..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**addCartLink()** function is used to create top cart link in magento.
Either rewrite **Mage_Checkout_Block_Links** class and change **addCartLink()** function as follows
or simply copy **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php** and edit

```
 public function addCartLink()
{
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
            : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            $text = $this->__('Cart (%s)', $count);
        } elseif ($count > 0) {
            $text = $this->__('Cart (%s)', $count);
        } else {
            $text = $this->__('Cart (0)');
        }

        $parentBlock->removeLinkByUrl($this->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
        $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, 'id="top_cart"', 'class="top-link-cart"'); //add your custom class or id here
    }
    return $this;
}
```